# Word to describe the movement of a galloping horse's head

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word, an adjective, to substitute for 'back and forth' to describe the exerted forward reach then recoil action of a horse's head in a gallop.

'Reciprocate' and 'oscillate' are both problematic - one is precise, machine-like controlled, the other determined organically by gravity, or robotically like a metronome. 'Annuent' is an antiquated word for 'nod', as in a human head nod of assent (based on annuent muscles in head/neck) and fits nicely ... but is unconventional... e.g. "The annuent up-down motion of the horses' heads towards the finish post, ended when the camera froze the inside horse a nose in front".

Any thoughts on a better one?

Answer (score 3):

"Bobbing" comes to mind (if specific to a head's motion).

Comment: Yes, it's known as a head bob: https://www.bitlessbridle.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Article-3.pdf Well, done, by the way. New to me. :)

Comment: Include some good references and credible usage examples. Else this may be considered a comment, not an answer.